# How would I sort this array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have an array based off this video class:

```
Video::Video(string i, string j, string k, double l, int m) 
{
    title = i; 
    link = j; 
    comment = k; 
    length = l; 
    rating = m;
}
```

And each array element would look something like this:

```
videolist[i] = new Video(title, link, comment, length, rating);
```

Now let's say the user wanted to sort the array by length, with the longest videos going first. I would need to bubble sort the array based on the longest video. To do that I would need to make a function:

```
bool Video::longer(Video *other) 
{
    if (/*"other" is greater than the current largest video*/) 
    {
        /*"other" is now the current largest video*/
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So how would I go about isolating the length of the "other" video and comparing it to "m_length", the current longest video? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I would go for something of this sort :

Creating a vector of the Video class.

```
std::vector< Video > videoArr;
```

And for the sorting, you could use the `std::sort` present in `<algorithm>`.

All that you would need to do would be :

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector< Video > videoArr;

std::sort( videoArr.begin(), videoArr.end(), []( const Video& lhs, const Video& rhs )
{
   return lhs.length > rhs.length;
});
```

OR

```
// In C++14
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

 std::vector< Video > videoArr;

std::sort( videoArr.begin(), videoArr.end(), []( const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs )
{
   return lhs.length > rhs.length;
});
```

You could also implement the `< operator` or the `> operator` and implement the less than/greater than operator for your case.

Answer (score 1):

use `std::sort` with custom comparator.

```
bool cmp(const Video &i, const Video &j)
{
    return i.length > j.length;
}
```

and

```
std::sort(videolist,videolist+number_of_elements,cmp);
```

Comment: Why create extra copies?